# How installing Java Agent?

Tags: java, bytecode, agent, javaagents, on-the-fly

I would like to know how to use java agent and how to install java agent.
I handle for the first time java agent. 
So they are not familiar. 
So please explain in detail.

Comment: You might want to Google It.

Comment: You have to be more specific! Like on what OS? etc.

Comment: Do you have a java-agent you want to use? In that case consult its documentation. Otherwise, why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you actually mean agents as in instrumentation, check this tutorial:

http://www.javabeat.net/introduction-to-java-agents/

it will give you a quick start in writing your first agents and set up everything you need to get started.

Just on a side note: if you want specific, detailed answers, ask specific, detailed questions.